# Merge multiple .raw file into single wav file using Sox

Tags: audio, sox

Does any one know how to merge multiple raw audio file into single wav file. I am using Sox but any other tools also fine.

I am trying below commands, but i know something wrong here

**sox -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 -e signed-integer file1.raw file2.raw out.wav**

I am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all input file parameters **per file** (as RAW obviously does not have a header). Your initial guess was same as mine: that `-r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 -e signed-integer` applies to both `file1.raw` and `file2.raw`. It doesn't.

Here's how it should be done:

```
sox -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 -e signed-integer file1.raw -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 -e signed-integer file2.raw out.wav
```

You might want to add option `-m` for merge.